# Django TestCase 302, expecting 200

Tags: python, django, testcase

I am testing a django project / Randomization app
I try to test status code of the index template of Randomization app but it return 302 instead of 200

I found similar question in this forum and add the advices (create a client and a user in setup method) but it does not work in my case
my user is created (controled with a print) but still have 302

thanks for advices

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Preinclusion, Randomisation, Medicament, ListeRandomisation
from django.urls import reverse

# test de la page index du module randomization
class IndexPageTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('Slater', 'slater@surfeur.com', 'mereva2019')

    def test_index_page(self):
        self.client.post('/accounts/login/?next=/randomization', {'username': 'Slater', 'password': 'mereva2019'})
        response = self.client.get(reverse('randomization:index'))
        # print(response['location'])
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
```

Comment: Does by any chance your `randomization:index` endpoint return `redirect(to_some_other_url)`? If so then either use `follow=True` or much more sophisticated assertion [assertRedirects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects).

Comment: no: return render(request, 'randomization/index.html', {'preincluded':preincluded}) ; if I use follow=True I got 404

Comment: Could you show the code of `randomizatin:index`? Also try breakpointing on mentioned return statement and making sure it stops there in this particuar test case when called from proper line `response = self.client.get(reverse('randomization:index'))`.

Comment: Hi makozaki ; I re-run my test with self.client.post('/registration/login/', {'username': 'Slater', 'password': 'mereva2019'}) and it pass ; I use Sublime Text and have no debug... try to use VS Code o have a more complete IDE ; thank for your help